# Rigify: Parent bones of some DEF-* bones

Tags: rigify

- Blender 2.83.3 (on macOS Catalina)
- Rigify 0.6.1

When I generate a rig from the basic human (or other) metarig, some generated DEF-* bones of the rig have ORG-* bones as its parent as below. Is this an intended design?

- The parent of DEF-upper_arm.L(R) is ORG-shoulder.L(R) instead of DEF-shoulder.L(R).
- The parent of DEF-breast.L(R) is ORG-brest.L(R) instead of DEF-spine.003.
- The parent of DEF-shoulder.L(R) is ORG-shoulder.L(R) instead of DEF-spine.003.
- The parent of DEF-thigh.L(R) is ORG-spine instead of DEF-spine.
- The parent of DEF-pelvis.L(R) is ORG-pelvis.L(R) instead of DEF-spine.

This behaviour causes that many unnecessary bones will be included when you export the rig as a FBX with “only deform bones” option, which is not suitable for the Unity projects (and the other Apps, I think). If you tweak these relations manually before exporting, you will get a pretty straightforward rig with only DEF-* bones.

Exporting as FBX is a major operation in Blender. I think it will be happy when I don’t need to tweak these bone relations manually every time I generate rigs with Rigify.

Thank you.